# How do I choose certain values in one column (based on another) to match with a column in another sheet, for the purpose of copy-paste?

Tags: vba, loops, conditional-statements, match, copy-paste

I am trying to loop through a list of salespeople (column A) and clients (columns B and C) in "Sheet1".

I want to go through column A of "Sheet1", and based on salesperson, refer to columns B & C (within the range of that salesperson), and compare it with column A in "Sheet2". If the values in columns B or C from "Sheet1" match a value in column A of "Sheet2", I want to copy that entire row, and paste it in a new "Sheet3".

I have been working with loops & conditionals, have figured out how to copy and paste based on condition from another sheet, but am struggling with the link between specifying columns B & C, based on column A from "Sheet1", and then matching those to column A of "Sheet2".

I can find something in a sheet and copy and paste to another sheet, but it is just a small part of what I want to do:

```
Sub CopyCode()

Dim r As Long, endrow As Long, pasterowindex As Long

endrow = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  pasterowindex = 1

For r = 1 To endrow 'Loop through sheet1 and search for your criteria

    'Central CODE:
    If Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(r, Columns("A").Column).Value = "CLIENT" Then
        'get all value(s) in range of column d  (and c eventually) 
        ' and see if they match values in column A of Readership paste
        'if they do match values in column A of readership paste,
        ' then copy that matched row into a new sheet
        ' (will be designated by salesperson)

        'Copy the current row
        Rows(r).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Switch to the sheet where you want to paste it & paste
        Sheets("Sheet3").Select
        Rows(pasterowindex).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
        pasterowindex = pasterowindex + 1

        'Switch back to your table & continue to search for your criteria
        Sheets("sheet2").Select
    End If

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Show what code you have and it will help us give you the pointers you need.  Put the code in your original post not the comments or as an answer.

Comment: Is the row you want to copy to sheet 3 on sheet 1 or sheet 2?

Comment: The row I want copy/paste is on sheet 2. I want to paste it on a third sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i = FirstRowA to LastRowA 'leaving you to figure out how to find these values
     If cell(i) <> vbNullString Then
          for h = FirstRowB to LastRowB 'again for you to figure out
               If cell(h) = cell(i) Then 
                    cell(h).copy
                    Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).value = "Column b"
               End If
          Next h

          for j = FirstRowC to LastRowC 'again you figure this out
               If cell(j) = cell(i) Then 
                    cell(j).copy
                    Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).value = "column c"
               end if
          Next j
      end if
next i
```

there might be some syntax issues here, but I have basically given you the loop you asked for. This just get you to the point where you can figure the rest out on your own with ease.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is pretty comprehensive. Could you maybe just explain quickly what vbnullstring represents here? I interpreted it as being (referencing my original question) the "salesperson"?

Comment: vbNullString is the built in function/keyword that VBA recognizes as NULL. It's more efficient to use vbNullString as opposed to "" to reference blanks. I just make it a habit to use it always when possible in regards to blank. Basically, its says if cell(i), the current cell in the loop, is not blank, then execute code

Comment: @Wick does this answer your question? If so please mark an answer or ask for more :)

Comment: Doug - still working on a final product, but yes, it definitely helped move me in the right direction! thanks!